# material-ui date picker color change

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, styles, material-ui

im trying to change the text color of material-ui date picker, only the button that opens the selector but nothing works.

here is my code:

```
    <ThemeProvider >
        <DatePicker
            autoOk
            label="Receipt Date"
            clearable
            disableFuture
            value={selectedDate}
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            margin="normal"
            color="primary"
        />
    </ThemeProvider >
```

my result is this and i want to change this to white.
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEEar.png)